# Obtener valor parámetro de salida PHP llamando un stored procedure de MySQL con parámetros de entrada y salida

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema para obtener el valor del parámetro de salida en PHP. Básicamente, la consulta siguiente funciona correctamente, los valores se insertan en una tabla en MySQL y, como notarán, tiene dos parámetros de salida (@sFinal, @sErrorFinal) de los cuales me gustaría obtener su resultado, sin embargo, a pesar de haber visto muchas indicaciones, no he podido lograrlo. Me gustaría que el parámetro de salida @sFinal fuese la información que recibe el return, algo así como return @sFinal.

```
static public function MdlIngresarVentas($tabla, $datos){

    $sql = 'call Sales_Actualizar(:nroRegistro, :registrosTotales, :cantidad, :precioVenta, 
                                  :totalVenta, :fechaVenta, :tipoVenta, :usuario, 
                                  :idMedicamento, :codigoBarra, @sFinal, @sErrorFinal)';

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(":nroRegistro", $datos["consecutivo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":registrosTotales", $datos["registrosTotal"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cantidad", $datos["cantidad"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":precioVenta", $datos["prventa"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":totalVenta", $datos["total"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fechaVenta", $datos["fechaVenta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tipoVenta", $datos["tipo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":idMedicamento", $datos["idMedicamento"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":codigoBarra", $datos["codigo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";    

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = null;


}
```

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1):

Los resultados de salida los recibes en forma de columnas como cualquier `SELECT`.

Podrías, por ejemplo, cambiar las lineas cuando ejecutas el comando por:

```
if($resultado = $stmt->execute()){

    // mostramos los resultadss
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($resultado);
     echo '</pre>';

    return "ok";

}else{

    return "error";

}
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/